# Suggest improvement for simple Cobol program

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I'm an "aspiring" programmer currently trying to learn Cobol. The code below is obviously a very simple Cobol program with hard-coded values. However I am curious to know how a more experienced Cobol programmer would improve such simple program. Maybe there are a lot of things I am missing?

Feel free to suggest how you would accomplish it.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   
   DATA DIVISION.
   
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   
   01  WORK-FIELDS.
       05  EMPTY-LINE      PIC X(132)  VALUE SPACES.
       
   01  HEADLINE.
       05      VALUE "Invoice Specification".
       
   01  FOOTER.

       05      VALUE "Invoice End".
    
   01  CALC-FIELDS.

           10  SPOILER           PIC 9(4).
           10  WINDSHIELD        PIC 9(3).
           10  PARTSUM           PIC 9(4).
           10  DISCOUNT          PIC 9(4).
           10  TO-PAY-EXKL       PIC 9(6).
           10  VAT               PIC 9(3).
           10  TOTAL-TO-PAY      PIC 9(4).

   
   01  PRINT-FIELDS.
           
       05  GROUP-1.
           10                  PIC X(36)
           VALUE  "01 SPOILER left-front, 1250:-".
           10  SPOILER-EDITED PIC Z,ZZZ.99.
           10                  PIC X(2)    VALUE ":-".
 
       05  GROUP-2.
           10                  PIC X(36)
           VALUE  "02 Windshield, 390:-".
           10  WINDSHIELD-EDITED PIC Z,ZZZ.99.
           10                  PIC X(2)    VALUE ":-".

       05  GROUP-3.
           10                  PIC X(36)
           VALUE  "Part Sum".
           10  PARTSUM-EDITED PIC Z,ZZZ.99.
           10                  PIC X(2)    VALUE ":-".
           
       05  GROUP-4.
           10                  PIC X(36)
           VALUE  "Discount 15%".
           10  DISCOUNT-EDITED   PIC Z,ZZZ.99.
           10                  PIC X(2)    VALUE ":-".
           
       05  GROUP-5.
           10                  PIC X(36)
           VALUE  "To Pay exkl VAT".
           10  TO-PAY-EDITED   PIC Z,ZZZ.99.
           10                  PIC X(2)    VALUE ":-".
           
       05  GROUP-6.
           10                  PIC X(36)
           VALUE  "Added VAT 25%".
           10 VAT-EDITED      PIC Z,ZZZ.99.
           10                  PIC X(2)    VALUE ":-".
       
       05  GROUP-7.
           10                  PIC X(36)
           VALUE  "Total Amount to Pay".
           10                  PIC X(4)    VALUE "SEK ".
           10  TOTAL-EDITED   PIC Z,ZZZ.99.
           10                  PIC X(2)    VALUE ":-".
           

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   
   100-GENERATE-INVOICE.
       
       PERFORM 200-CALCULATE.
       PERFORM 300-PRINT-VALUES.
       
       STOP RUN.
       
   200-CALCULATE.
       
       MOVE 1250 TO SPOILER
       MOVE SPOILER TO SPOILER-EDITED
       MOVE 390  TO WINDSHIELD
       MOVE WINDSHIELD TO WINDSHIELD-EDITED
       
       ADD SPOILER WINDSHIELD TO PARTSUM
       MOVE PARTSUM TO PARTSUM-EDITED

       MULTIPLY PARTSUM BY 0.15 GIVING DISCOUNT
       MOVE DISCOUNT TO DISCOUNT-EDITED
       
       SUBTRACT DISCOUNT FROM PARTSUM GIVING TO-PAY-EXKL
       MOVE TO-PAY-EXKL TO TO-PAY-EDITED
       
       MULTIPLY TO-PAY-EXKL BY 0.25 GIVING VAT
       MOVE VAT TO VAT-EDITED
       
       MULTIPLY TO-PAY-EXKL BY 1.25 GIVING TOTAL-TO-PAY
       MOVE TOTAL-TO-PAY TO TOTAL-EDITED
       .
   
   300-PRINT-VALUES.
           
       DISPLAY HEADLINE
       DISPLAY EMPTY-LINE
       DISPLAY EMPTY-LINE
       DISPLAY GROUP-1
       DISPLAY GROUP-2
       DISPLAY GROUP-3
       DISPLAY GROUP-4
       DISPLAY GROUP-5
       DISPLAY GROUP-6
       DISPLAY EMPTY-LINE
       DISPLAY GROUP-7
       DISPLAY EMPTY-LINE
       DISPLAY EMPTY-LINE
       DISPLAY FOOTER
       .
```

Comment: That's a reasonable approach but SO doesn't work like that, it is a Q+A site "problem X solution Y". https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be the stack-exchange match, or a COBOL discussion board like https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/discussion/cobol - I suggest to move the question to one of those and delete it here.

Comment: Generally, a "real" COBOL program would read a file and write the report to an output file.  Otherwise, your code looks fine.

Comment: Thank you Gilbert, your comment was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the objective of this code. Things to consider:

1. Determine objectives
2. Determine inputs and outputs
3. Design input file/db access mode (sequential/random/start from a criteria...etc.).
4. Identify the business rules.
5. Design the output (will you just produce a result via display only, will you update a database? will you print a report?)
6. Design a flow for the processing expected.
7. Code the required parts.
   Note that your code above has no PROCEDURE DIVISION.

Maybe some code here could help amongst the ton of code already out there:
[Sample Code](http://www.csis.ul.ie/cobol/examples/default.htm)